Incoming mail does not work on Kubuntu 22.04
my incoming mail does not work even if I have postfix and dovecot set correctly. It was working without problems and suddenly it doesn't work. I have this in the log, what is it?The specified user does not exist and is repeating with different usernames.
Apr 02 12:43:11 auth: Debug: client passdb out: FAIL 11 user=midget@wxxxx.fun
Apr 02 12:43:09 auth: Debug: auth(midget@wxxxx.fun,194.169.175.10): Auth request finished
Apr 02 12:43:09 auth: Debug: sql(midget@wxxxx.fun,194.169.175.10): Finished passdb lookup
Apr 02 12:43:09 auth-worker(31679): Debug: conn unix:auth-worker (pid=24864,uid=128): auth-worker<46>: Finished: user_unknown
Apr 02 12:43:09 auth-worker(31679): Debug: conn unix:auth-worker (pid=24864,uid=128): auth-worker<46>: sql(midget@wxxxx.fun,194.169.175.10 ): Finished passdb lookup
Apr 02 12:43:09 auth-worker(31679): Info: conn unix:auth-worker (pid=24864,uid=128): auth-worker<46>: sql(midget@wxxxx.fun,194.169.175.10 ): unknown user
Apr 02 12:43:09 auth-worker(31679): Debug: mysql(localhost): Finished query 'SELECT username AS user,password FROM mailbox WHERE username = 'midget@wxxxx.fun' AND active='1'' in 0 msec
Apr 02 12:43:09 auth-worker(31679): Debug: conn unix:auth-worker (pid=24864,uid=128): auth-worker<46>: sql(midget@wxxxx.fun,194.169.175.10 ): query: SELECT username AS user,password FROM mailbox WHERE username = 'midget@wxxxx.fun' AND active='1'
Apr 02 12:43:09 auth-worker(31679): Debug: conn unix:auth-worker (pid=24864,uid=128): auth-worker<46>: sql(midget@wxxxx.fun,194.169.175.10 ): Performing passdb lookup
Apr 02 12:43:09 auth-worker(31679): Debug: conn unix:auth-worker (pid=24864,uid=128): auth-worker<46>: Handling PASSV request
Apr 02 12:43:09 auth: Debug: sql(midget@wxxxx.fun,194.169.175.10): Performing passdb lookup
Apr 02 12:43:09 auth: Debug: client in: CONT 11 MXEydzNlNHI= (previous base64 data may contain sensitive data)
Apr 02 12:43:03 auth: Debug: client passdb out: CONT 11 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Apr 02 12:43:03 auth: Debug: client in: CONT 11 bWlkZ2V0QHdlYmxhbmQuZnVu (previous base64 data may contain sensitive data)


Hi and welcome to the site! I am afraid this really isn't clear. Please take a step back and start from the beginning: how have you set up your email? What log are you looking at? What doesn't work? Sending? Receiving? Both? Also, you might want to clean the log and remove the real IP you have shared.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
